# Gradient descent converging towards the wrong value

Tags: c++, linear-regression, gradient-descent, convergence

I'm trying to implement a gradient descent algorithm in C++. Here's the code I have so far :

```
#include <iostream>

double X[] {163,169,158,158,161,172,156,161,154,145};
double Y[] {52, 68, 49, 73, 71, 99, 50, 82, 56, 46 };
double m, p;
int n = sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0]);

int main(void) {
    double alpha = 0.00004; // 0.00007;
    m = (Y[1] - Y[0]) / (X[1] - X[0]);
    p = Y[0] - m * X[0];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        gradientStep(alpha);
    }
    return 0;
}

double Loss_function(void) {
    double res = 0;
    double tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp =  Y[i] - m * X[i] - p;
        res += tmp * tmp;
    }
    return res / 2.0 / (double)n;
}

void gradientStep(double alpha) {
    double pg = 0, mg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pg += Y[i] - m * X[i] - p;
        mg += X[i] * (Y[i] - m * X[i] - p);
    }
    p += alpha * pg / n;
    m += alpha * mg / n;
}
```

This code converges towards m = 2.79822, p = -382.666, and an error of 102.88. But if I use my calculator to find out the correct linear regression model, I find that the correct values of m and p should respectively be 1.601 and -191.1.

I also noticed that the algorithm won't converge for alpha > 0.00007, which seems quite low, and the value of p barely changes during the 8 iterations (or even after 2000 iterations).

What's wrong with my code?

[Here](http://file:///home/mmeloux/T%C3%A9l%C3%A9chargements/TMI04.2_linear_regression.pdf)'s a good overview of the algorithm I'm trying to implement. The values of theta0 and theta1 are called p and m in my program.

[Other implementation in python](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/24/gradient-descent-linear-regression/)

[More about the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)

Comment: Could you share a link the mathematical formulation that you've been implementing with this code? I'm not a maths programming expert, but I might suggest too small values somewhere, i.e. denormals, or a plain divergence between the formulation and the implementation.

Comment: Also, are you sure that `return res / 2.0 / (double)n;` does what you intend it to do (taking into account operator  associativity)?

Comment: Here's a link to a similar implementation in Python : https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/24/gradient-descent-linear-regression/

You an also read more about it here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent

For the line you mention, I'm trying to return 1/2n * res, which is why I wrote it this way. But the loss function is only a means of checking the result, and it doesn't change the values obtained in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://www-prima.inrialpes.fr/Prima/Homepages/jlc/Courses/2015/ENSI2.SIRR/ENSI2.SIRR.S2.pdf) gives a comprehensive view of the algorithm; it turns out I was following a completely wrong approach.

The following code does not work properly (and I have no plans to work on it further), but should put on track anyone who's confronted to the same problem as me :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<double> vect;

std::vector<double> y, omega(2, 0), omega2(2, 0);;
std::vector<std::vector<double>> X;
int n = 10;

int main(void) {
    /* Initialize x so that each members contains (1, x_i) */
    /* Initialize x so that each members contains y_i */
    double alpha = 0.00001;
    display();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        gradientStep(alpha);
        display();
    }
    return 0;
}

double f_function(const std::vector<double> &x) {
    double c;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < omega.size(); i++) {
        c += omega[i] * x[i];
    }
    return c;
}

void gradientStep(double alpha) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < X[0].size(); j++) {
            omega2[j] -= alpha/(double)n * (f_function(X[i]) - y[i]) * X[i][j];
        }
    }
    omega = omega2;
}

void display(void) {
    double res = 0, tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp = y[i] - f_function(X[i]);
        res += tmp * tmp; // Loss functionn
    }

    std::cout << "omega = ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < omega.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "[" << omega[i] << "] ";
    }
    std::cout << "\tError : " << res * .5/(double)n << std::endl;
}
```